# Is Work Manager correct way to delete uploaded files in Android?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-workmanager

I am creating an application where I create a post and add attachments to it.
After an image is uploaded to Firebase Storage, the user can delete the attachment.

I am using Work Manager to delete the file as it is intended for deferrable and guaranteed execution. So my intention was to let the user click a button to delete and not wait for it to finish. Some how I am still wondering if there is any problem with it.

I am using OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder and I am passing it data for building storage reference

```
// Repository
            val workArray = mutableListOf<OneTimeWorkRequest>()
            val work = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<CancelUploadWorkManager>()
                .setInputData(getInputData(index, userId = userId, fileName = fileName))
                .setConstraints(Constraints.Builder().setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED).build())
                .build()
            workArray.add(work)

            WorkManager.getInstance()
            .enqueue(workArray)
```

```
// CancelUploadWorkManager

class CancelUploadWorkManager(context: Context, params: WorkerParameters): CoroutineWorker(context, params) {

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        val position: Int = inputData.getInt(Constants.KEY_POSITION, 0)
        val userId = inputData.getString(Constants.KEY_DIRECTORY)
        val fileName = inputData.getString(Constants.KEY_FILE_NAME)

        return try {
            FirebaseManager().deleteAt(position = position, fileName = fileName!!,userId = userId!!)
            Timber.i("Work Manager executed")
            Result.success()
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            Timber.e(ex)
            Result.retry()
        }

    }
}
```

Expected: File should be deleted with a guarantee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is Work Manager correct way to delete uploaded files in Android?

Yes. The [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) API lets you schedule background tasks that need guaranteed completion, whether or not the app process is around. The WorkManager is available only on devices running API 14 and higher.

However, [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) is available on devices running API 21 and higher. So for devices running API 14 and higher, including devices without Google Play services, WorkManager provides capabilities that are like those provided by JobScheduler.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear, but it seems like you're saying that this code isn't running properly.  If that's the case, what is FirebaseManager.deleteAt?  Is it synchronous or asynchronous?

Comment: I have added the code as an overview of what I am doing. My code is running, I just wanted to know if using WorkManager to delete uploaded files is ideal or not. I want to know how people do it in 2019, do they create the feature to schedule deletion on the server or is it okay to just create OneTimeRequestBuilder from WorkManager and let it do it whenever it can. About your question on synchronous or asynchronous, I am using suspend from Coruotines and thus runs in a different Dispatcher.